# SetTimeout will not work on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

On my website I have CD offers that rotate through every five seconds. This works on all browsers apart from internet explorer where it remains on the first CD.

```
function updateTarget( txt ) {
  'use strict';
   document.getElementById('offers').innerHTML = txt;
}

window.onload = function() {  // attach an onload handler
   getOffers();               // call the function below, getQuotes()
};

var getOffers = function() {
   // call getRequest with the url, the callback, displayQuotes, and false meaning not xml
   getRequest('getOffers.php', updateTarget, false);
   setTimeout(getOffers, 5000);    // set a timer to call this same function again in 5 seconds
};
```

I have tried setting the date in the header to a date in the past but this did not work. I have tried to use setinterval but again no luck.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I have used this in an earlier version of the code, it did not fix the problem however I will probably go back to using it once the IE problem has been resolved.

Comment: @Hyperd `setInterval` can freeze the browser if the interval is too small. If an exception prevents clearing `setInterval`, it will run forever.

Comment: Probably, an error is throws somewhere. Open the developer tools and see.

Comment: Yeah, IE should fire the setTimeout. I assume getRequest is async. The issue is probably there. If you are using Chrome, take a look at the network tab in the developer tools

Comment: @Oriol I have checked in the developers console and there are no errors that are being thrown.

Comment: Use `alert(1)` at the beginning of your script to confirm that it runs. Move it to the line after the code that doesn't run to confirm the alert doesn't run neither. Then use a binary search to find where the problem is.

Comment: @oriol thanks. Tried and everything seems to be working fine (again with google chrome) but when opened in IE nothing occurs for some reason.

Comment: So the alert does not run at the beginning of the script neither? That probably means IE can't download the script

Comment: Just a quick update guys I have managed to get it to work but only when I inspect the element. If I go back off inspect element then the CD's no longer change. 

The only alteration that I have made is that I put the date from the past back in the PHP header- if anyone has had something like this before then please let me know.